# c# Regex for all except single,double quotes and comma

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get a regex working but cannot get it right. I am trying to write a regex c# that would allow all special chars except comma, single quotes & double quotes. But cant get it to work.

I have the below code:

```
 Regex alphaNumericRegex = new Regex(@"^[\w]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

I tried using

```
^[^'",][a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]|\:;<>.?/]*$
```

where I thought the first negate [] set is for the chars which I dont want to allow.

But this does not work. There must be a simpler way to do this.

Sorry I know there are many regex posts around but somehow I cant get mine to work even after reading them.

Would appreciate inputs.

Comment: Do you mean to write `@"^[^""',]*$"` matching a string consisting of any 0+ chars other than double and single quotes and commas?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You should post this as the answer.

Comment: Karen, what is the trouble here? Do you want to say you just failed to use a double quote in the string literal? I guess that was the main trouble with getting at the right expression.

Comment: Yes thanks for this wiktor. This works fine. I had missing double quotes. Also I thought we had to use all the chars list which we also want to allow, which is not the case though.

Answer (score -1):

By changing your regex to the following, you will allow all characters except commas, single quotes and double quotes.

```
Regex alphaNumericRegex = new Regex(@"^[^""',]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```